# WS-Addressing ReplyTo for callbacks in asynchronous bpel-processes

Tags: bpel, ws-addressing, apache-ode

I have an asynchronous bpel-processes that invokes a cllback-service on the client to transmit its response. At the moment, I statically defined the client's endpoint in the corresponding wsdl-file and everything works fine.

Now I am trying to have ODE not use the WSDL address, but to extract the replyTo address from the initial call from the client. I provide WS-Addressing headers with an `<wsa:replyTo>` in the initial call. However, this doesn't seem to work. Do I have to make any changes to my process in order for ODE to use the endpoint specified in the ws-adressing headers?

**Edit:**
As this doesn't seem to work, I implemented a work-around: Apache-ODE allows BPEL-processes to read Data from arbitrary SOAP-headers. I used this feature to read the content of the provided  `<wsa:replyTo>`-header and assign it as endpoint to the client-partnerlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand it correctly that you want to use a dual channel binding using WS-Addressing? This is currently not supported by the official Apache ODE builds but is on the roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already implemented a work-around as described in the question.